# Did Ubuntu switch from overlayfs to aufs between 16.04.1 and 16.04.2?

Tags: live-usb, live-environment, overlayfs

In Ubuntu 16.04.1, booting a live USB and typing `mount` reveals that / is mounted as an OverlayFS with a squashfs filesystem as the lower directory and a ramdisk as the upper directory.

However, booting to a Ubuntu 16.04.2 live USB and typing `mount` shows that / is mounted as an aufs instead of an overlayfs.

Ubuntu 17.04 and any later versions seem to use aufs as well, while 16.04.1 and earlier versions all use overlayfs.

Why did this change occur between the Ubuntu 16.04.1 and 16.04.2 CD images? Is this related to an update to casper? It seems like a weird change to have been made, as I thought Ubuntu 16.04 was supposed to have been feature-frozen.

Comment: As an aside, the Ubuntu 16.04.2 image also seems to be missing curl, while 16.04.1 came with it.

Comment: Yes, the live (and persistent live) sessions look slightly different, but I do not notice any important difference in the functionalilty. I do not know why it was changed, but yes, I think it 'belongs to casper'. 16.04 LTS and 16.04.1 LTS come with the xenial kernel, but 16.04.2 LTS comes with the yakkety kernel, and new features can be introduced with this point release and subsequent point releases. - By the way, have you noticed any problem because of this change from `cow` to `aufs`?